# Is an invalid CSS left property acceptable?

Tags: html, css

I found some strange behaviour, at least for me. I will appreciate if someone explains this to me.

This code works as expected only in Firefox, and in Chrome or Opera, the red block 1px right from desired position.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  height: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

And if I just chage left property to some invalid value `left: invalid` and remove transform, it works fine in other browsers that I tested.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: invalid;

  height: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

---

**My configuration**

*System*: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

*Browsers*:

- Firefox 84.0.2 (64-bit)
- Opera Version: 73.0.3856.344
- Chromium Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

I also noticed that this occurs only when width is even.

Comment: JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/u3eo4gq8/2/

Comment: Both the code snippets seem to yield same result for me in chrome and ff. also there is no value as `invalid` to css `left` property. more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left

Comment: @Nik I think the OP wanted to give an *invalid* value to `left`, and `invalid` was the first *invalid* value that came to their mind...

Comment: @FZs yes that could be possible.

Comment: I cannot see any displacement of the red box on Chrome (or Edge) on my Windows10 laptop. What system are you using and what browser version numbers?

Comment: @AHaworth, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and browsers are: Firefox 84.0.2 (64-bit) which works fine, Opera Version: 73.0.3856.344 and Chromium Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) snap (64-bit), in the last two the div position incorrect. Also I notice that this occurs only when width is even.

Comment: Have you tried border say 2px? Also might be worth trying without border-box. I’ve seen a similar thing with odd/even pixel calculations in the past, something to do with screen pixels being several CSS pixels but I can’t get yours to go wrong on W10 or IOS I’m afraid.

Comment: @AHaworth, without border-box things stay the same, with bigger border it just becomes less noticeble. So it seems that some versions of browsers simply round up the result of the percentage-to-pixel conversion in the transform function.

Comment: Yes, I think that sounds very feasible. If you animate a transition on a border you can on some systems end up with a trail of demi-pixels. It seems to happen particularly on borders.

Comment: I have now managed to see the displacement in Chrome on W10 by altering the window width - it does look as though your even/odd speculation is along the right lines.

Answer (score -1):

The reason there's no visual difference is that the `left: 50%` property *pushes* the element by 50% of its parent, and the `transform: translateX(-50%)` property *pushes back* the element by 50%, i.e. pushes the element forward by -50%, in the X direction, of its own width.

In the second code snippet, since the value `invalid` is indeed *invalid*, the browser ignored it. Also, since there's no translate, it doesn't push anyway either. So, there is no difference in the UI.